# Windows 10 - Randomly drops display

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hp-pavilion

I'm using Windows 10 on an HP EliteBook and when I am at work I have it hooked up to 2 additional displays. Specs attached at the bottom of the post.

If I put the machine to sleep/lock the screen, often when I return, the machine awakens/unlocks without issue, but the native laptop display is now no longer recognized. It's not until I go into system settings, and "Detect" that it is reconsidered as a connected display.

In addition, randomly throughout the day, the entire set of screens will go blank for two-three seconds, and it appears to be a display connection reset of some sort. (On further reflection, I'm wondering if this is related to an issue with the magnifier application; it only happens when that is activated. The first, and major issue is persistent regardless of magnifier.)

**My questions are**: Is this a known issue, or am I abusing my video card? If it is an issue, is there a workaround? Or should I be exercising my warranty?

Edit: I looked up the max resolution for the Intel HD Graphics 520 video card and my monitors take up only about 84% of it. Similarly, it advertises that it can support 3 displays. So it should be built to handle this use case.

[image: laptop specs attached here] 
[image: display specs attached here]

Comment: Do you use the [latest video drivers](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/88355/Intel-HD-Graphics-520)? Note that the sum total of resolutions is 5560x4440, which is considerable, so the total amount of allocated VRAM is important. Please see [this article](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000020962/graphics-drivers.html), section "How much graphics memory does my computer have?" and add the information to the post.

Answer (score 1):

You should verify that you are using the latest video drivers from Intel.
See the page [Downloads for Intel® HD Graphics 520](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/88355/Intel-HD-Graphics-520).

If you are using the latest drivers, note that the sum total of resolutions
of all your monitors is 5560x4440, which is considerable, so the total amount
of allocated Video RAM (VRAM) is important.

Intel HD Graphics is an integrated graphics card, meaning that it is an integral
part of the motherboard and has no memory of its own.
It allocates its memory from your system RAM, which is done by the BIOS.

To increase the system memory dedicated to the Intel HD Graphics adapter,
enter the BIOS, which is usually done by pressing
<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>Del</kbd>
during boot.

When you enter the BIOS, look for an option named something like
"Intel HD Graphics share memory setting".
It may be under a tab named "Advanced" or "Chipset configuration" or similar.
Change the settings and press the Save key to save and reboot
(<kbd>F10</kbd> in most cases).

The maximum possible allocation is said to be around 1.5 GB, but take care
not to cripple the operating system by allocating too much video memory.
The total amount of memory should be taken into account, rather than blindly
changing this setting to the maximum.

If you are a laptop user, your laptop may not have such a setting for changing
the amount of video memory. Not all laptops have it.

Comment: @jameselmore: Any comments?

Comment: I would add: Update the BIOS. Then make a ticket with HP.